# MATLAB SQLite Error: Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: matlab, sqlite, odbc

I'm trying to import a SQLite database I created in Python to MATLAB to add some data I have there to it. Whenever I try to import the file, I get the error in the title name. I did a bit of reading and found that there are 32 and 64-bit drivers for these databases. My MATLAB version is 64-bit and my operating system is also 64-bit, so I shouldn't have a problem, right?

I opened the odbcad32.exe file in system 32 (where the 64-bit version is kept) and I get this.

[image]

So does this mean I can't open the database in 64-bit MATLAB? I'm so confused... All the help documents just say 'open the exe file', nothing changes in MATLAB.